# I want to develop an application for making vAnimated videos how to proceed?

Tags: php, html, asp.net, video, ffmpeg

I have done some research on internet about ffmpeg which provides solution for this.
Can anyone suggest me in which technology i should go for desktop based application or web based application would be fine.
  Also if there is any other gif image generators available.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

SO is **not a free coding or code conversion or tutorial or library finding service**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for web based application instead of desktop based application. Web appplication can be accessed from anywhere and from any device mobile or pc or tab. Desktop application on the other hand will be dependent only for that machine. Just go with the one which serves the business purpose very well.

For generating images you can use the PHP's image library. Check the below link :

http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php[enter link description here](http://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice Adi. I have tried implementing code which you have provided but unfortunately its throwing an error while generating gif file. http://screencast.com/t/bhbDc3I8JUCT

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried to implement.

Comment: I found out that error within their code was throwing from GIFEncoder class. See screenshot http://screencast.com/t/aezzQRJ0j7l

Comment: Remove the comma in the end from the last array element . i.e : ERRO3 and try once.

Comment: How do I install ffmpeg on my server ?

Comment: Which server are you using Linux based ? If it is linux  based then probably you will have a cpanel for it. I think you can install it from there.